# Different method for collision detection using faces of a rectangle

Tags: c#, xna, collision-detection, physics

I have been working on and off of a certain game I'm making (trying to get it finished!) and a problem that has been unsolved for a while in it is the collision detection between a ball and a square.

Basically what I want to happen eventually is depending on the angle/way the rectangle is facing, I want the ball to bounce of it accordingly (I know I could just inverse the ball direction before/as it hit the square).

At the moment though, my current problem is trying to inverse the correct X and Y components depending on the side/face that the ball collides with the square, e.g. if the ball hits the right side of the square, then I need to inverse the ball's X component.

This doesn't seem to work and I was wondering if I could somehow label each side of the rectangle, in terms of for the top of it label that 'face 1' or something, then for the right side of it 'face 2' or 'side 2', etc...

I have provided some code below (this is the code I'm using now):

```
//(collision with right side of square)
if (theBall.GetRectangle.Left <= thePaddle.GetRectangle.Right)
{
    theBall.pVelocity.X = -theBall.pVelocity.X;
}

//(collision with bottom of square)
if (theBall.GetRectangle.Top <= thePaddle.GetRectangle.Bottom)
{
    theBall.pVelocity.Y = -theBall.pVelocity.Y;
}
```

I have written the code for the other 2 sides of the rectangle but they are just the opposite of the two above, i.e. for collision with top of rectangle = opposite of bottom, etc.

EDIT: the object I am checking against if the ball has collided with DOES NOT move, I mean it only rotates... so I don't know if this is important (it probably is, therefore I apologise for missing this info out at the start).

EDIT @ 23:36: ok, I have tried something.... and it hasn't worked... :(

```
public Vector2 DistBetweenBallAndBlock(Paddle thePaddle, Ball theBall)
    {
        Vector2 centreOfBall = new Vector2(theBall.Texture.Width / 2, theBall.Texture.Height / 2);

        float distX = thePaddle.Position.X - centreOfBall.X;
        float distY = thePaddle.Position.Y - centreOfBall.Y;

        if (distX < 0)
        {
            distX = -distX;
        }

        if (distY < 0)
        {
            distY = -distY;
        }


        return new Vector2(distX, distY);
    }
```

I have then tried to just print the result just to get an idea of what's going on and what sort of values are being output:

```
Vector2 a = ball.DistBetweenBallAndBlock(paddle1, ball);            
        angleOfPaddle = Math.Atan2(a.Y, a.X);
```

I then just print this value to screen, however I am getting the same result of 0.63...

Comment: Are you for some reason *not* using purely radius based collision for the ball? It's rather nice to only worry about distance for circular objects.

Comment: Nope im not. I sort of know what you mean but i don't really know the sort of code to write for it...

Comment: Essentially, you create a vector between the center of the ball and the nearest point on the object you're checking against, and if it's length is below the radius of the circle, there's a collision. Getting the nearest point is more difficult, but you'd probably do it by finding the two nearest corners and then finding the closest point along them. Now I feel like looking up vector formulas :D

Answer (score 1):

To detect a collision between `Rectangle`s you could use `Rectangle.Intersect` method, instead of checking the objects' sides.

And to detect which side of the rectangle is hit, you can compute the `Vector2` between the ball center and the rectangle center. Getting its angle with `Math.Atan2` you can easily know which face of the rectangle has been hit.

Comment: Your answer is much easier than mine, and probably what he should use in this case, though corners may not collide well.

Comment: Yeah, I know, they are a bit difficult to handle in any case I think.

Comment: Yea, what i have done/am doing is checking to see if there is a collision using the rectangle.intersect method and then inside the if statement using other checks to try to see which side of the rectangle the ball has collided with to perform the correct operations. I don't really understand Math.Atan2, i mean i have read about it on tutorials and stuff but i wouldn't say im a maths whiz, well not rly in trigonometry anyways lol... so if you could either briefly explain it or tell me a good link to read about it that would be awesome thanks... in the mean time i will use google lol

Comment: It's not so hard to understand: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.atan2(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: thanks, yea i was reading that just after i posted my last comment. I do understand it but what i don't really understand is how i would implement it in my code, i mean using vectors... sorry if im being a bit dumb... lol

thanks

Comment: you just need: `double angle = Math.Atan2(vector.Y, vector.X)` and then use that angle to detect which is the side been hit. Of course vector is the distance between ball and rect.

Comment: could i just draw a line between the center of the ball and the square and try to see which side the ball is compared to the rectangle and then see which side of the square the line intersects.... AHH im this is so frustrating lol... (as much as it is for you probably getting me to understand your solutions... lol i apologise)

Comment: Why do you want to draw that line?

Comment: oh... sorry i meant draw not in terms of actually rendering the line but just in code... like behind the scenes just for calculations. Would it help if i put a youtube video up with my current problem and game just so you can see what i mean... would that be easier? Thanks

Comment: The only "line" you can calculate is the Vector2 between your objects, and you can obtain it with `Vector2.Subtract(centreOfBall, thePaddle.Position);`

Comment: Ok, thanks. I have decided to redesign my paddle, so now i think what i would require is to find the 'normal', i.e. where the point of contact between ball and paddle is 90 degrees... (sorry i assume you knew that but i mentioned it just to make myself clearer)

In terms of changing the paddle, i am going to make it so that its width is greater than its height

Answer (score 0):

Looked up some Vector stuff, based on my comment.

**Collision Style**

The optimal way of colliding with a circular object is to collide using a vector between it and the nearest point of the object you're checking against. If the distance is less than or equal to the radius of the circle, there is a collision. The advantages of this method are that you don't have to keep track of a rectangle, you get circular collision, and you get the angle of the collision from the vector.

**How You Do It**

I'll assume you have some strategy to keep from considering every object every frame, and keep to the basic problem. Your paddle has 4 vertices, one for each corner. Because your ball is essentially a vertex with a picture drawn over it, you can easily check the distance between the ball and each corner of your paddle. Two will be nearest. From there, it's just a matter of finding out if that edge collides. I found a solution to that [here](http://www.leadinglesson.com/problem-on-finding-the-nearest-point-on-a-line), which includes a nice formula.

Does that help?

Comment: at the moment, i am checking if the ball has collided with every object.... which sounds really stupid but i don't know a better way without making the code and everything appear messy or too complex or both. I understand parts of that link you provided but im not too great with vectors, i mean i have gone over some vector stuff but i don't really understand the method of finding x0... also i dont really know what it's trying to find... sorry im not with it today or something... :S Thanks btw